# Крашится браузер на ipad при аплоаде изображений

Tags: javascript, webbrowser, fileupload, ipad, jquery-file-upload

Есть страница, на которой нужно загружать много фотографий (от 40 до 200) прямо с ipad.  Для загрузки использую blueimp-file-upload. Когда количество изображений превышает какое-то значение (около 30-40) вкладка иногда начинает крашиться при очередной попытке загрузить изображение. То есть я жму на кнопку "Загрузить фото", в стандартном меню ipad выбираю "Сделать фото", фотографирую и сайт в этот момент крашиться.

```
var FormFileUploads = function (uploads) {
return {
    init: function () {
        // Инициализируем каждый input file из uploads
        var token = $('[name="image[_token]"]').val();
        for (var i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
            var $wrapper = $(uploads[i].wrapperId),
                imageType = uploads[i].name,
                entityType = uploads[i].type;
            if (!$wrapper.size()) {
                continue;
            }

            var id = getId();
            var addCallback = function ($wrapper, imageType, entityType) {
                return function (e, data) {
                    console.log("add callback");
                    stat['addCallback'] = new Date();
                    var imgId = 'id' + new Date().getTime();
                    $wrapper.find('.files').append(
                        '<div class="col-md-6 image-column">' +
                            '<table>' +
                                '<tr>' +
                                    '<td class="image-counter"><h4></h4></td>' +
                                    '<td>' +
                                        '<div class="image-wrapper">' +
                                            '<img id="' + imgId + '" class="image" />' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</td>' +
                                '</tr>' +
                            '</table>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );
                    var file = data.files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        stat['loaded'] = e.loaded;
                        var $img = $('#' + imgId);
                        $img.attr('src', e.target.result);
                        Metronic.blockUI({
                            target: $img.closest('.image-wrapper')
                        });
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    data.formData = {
                        "image[_token]": token,
                        "type": imageType,
                        "entityType": entityType,
                        'id': id,
                        'imgId': imgId
                    };
                    data.submit();
                }
            };
            var successCallback = function ($wrapper) {
                return function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    stat['successCallback'] = new Date();
                    var $image = $('#' + result.data.imgId);
                    if (result.success) {
                        var type = $wrapper.closest('.upload-form').attr('id');
                        var image = new Image();
                        image.onload = function () {
                            Metronic.unblockUI($image.closest('.image-wrapper'));
                            $image.replaceWith(
                                '<div class="image-button btn blue rotate-left" action="rotate-image" image-id="' + result.data.id + '">' +
                                    '<span class="icon-action-undo"></span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="image-button btn blue rotate-right" action="rotate-image" image-id="' + result.data.id + '">' +
                                    '<span class="icon-action-redo"></span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="image-button btn blue delete-button" action="delete-image" image-id="' + result.data.id + '">' +
                                    '<span class="icon-trash"></span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<a href="' + result.data.image + '" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-' + type + '">' +
                                    '<img src="' + result.data.preview + '" />' +
                                '</a>'
                            );
                            bindEvents();
                            isImageLoading = false;
                        };
                        image.src = result.data.preview;
                        stat['imgId'] = result.data.imgId;
                        stat['preview'] = result.data.preview;
                        stat['image'] = result.data.image;
                    } else {
                        $image.closest('.image-column').remove();
                        toastr.error(result.message, 'Ошибка');
                        Metronic.unblockUI($image.closest('.image-wrapper'));
                        isImageLoading = false;
                    }
                    stat['timeDiff'] = Math.round((stat['successCallback'] - stat['addCallback']) / 1000);
                    Utils.log('Client image was processed', stat);
                }
            };
            var progressCallback = function ($wrapper) {
                return function (e, data) {
                    var percent = Math.floor(data.loaded / data.total * 100);
                    var $progressWrapper = $wrapper.find('.fileupload-progress');
                    var $progress = $progressWrapper.find('.progress');
                    $progressWrapper.removeClass('fade');
                    $progress.attr('aria-valuenow', percent);
                    $progress.css('width', percent + '%');
                    if (percent == 100) {
                        $progressWrapper.addClass('fade');
                    }
                }
            };

            var errorCallback = function($wrapper) {
                return function(e, textStatus) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            };

            $wrapper.find('[type="file"]').fileupload({
                disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/.test(window.navigator.userAgent),
                maxFileSize: 5000000,
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
                add: addCallback($wrapper, imageType, entityType),
                success: successCallback($wrapper),
                progress: progressCallback($wrapper),
                error: errorCallback($wrapper)
            });
        }
    }
};
}(UploadConfig);
```

Как исправить это? Проблема воспроизводиться только на IPad.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не хватает памяти на выполнение операции, выносите тяжелые операции на воркеры. Одна страница в iOS не может превышать 10МБ

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под воркерами? Изображения грузятся по одному.

Comment: Я говорил про WebWorkers. Посмотрел я ваш код, думаю вам воркеры не помогут, только лимит на количество изображений.